# what does High-Noise-Immunity mean?

Tags: amplifier, dc-motor, logic-gates, datasheet, motor-controller

In l293d datasheet i found that term "High-Noise-Immunity" in the features. so what does it mean?
i didn't find anything explain what it means in the internet

Comment: it means the same as 'extra power', or 'smoother taste'. The product is doing something that's expected of it (like the inputs should have a certain level of protection in order to function safely), and the marketing people want to make it sound better than the competition. Maybe it's just got schmidt triggers on the inputs, which can reject small noise fluctuations?

Comment: Perhaps it means that noise voltage at the input terminals cannot falsely trigger the device output.

Comment: It just means Schmitt Trigger input.. but if you can switch to a FET driver , much lower driver loss than old BJT type  https://www.ti.com/motor-drivers/brushed-dc-bdc-drivers/products.html. Use twisted pairs for all wires to improve immunity.,

Answer (score 3):

It's right in front of you:

[image]

What they mean by "high noise immunity" is that it has a high (relative to TTL logic levels) threshold for switching between a low input level and a high input level. So small noise variations when the input voltage is low won't cause spurious switching.

In general, the bullet points on the front page of the datasheet are marketing and not technical. Sometimes they are useful for determining the intended application of a device, but you should generally ignore them and read the actual specification tables if you want to know how the device performs.

Comment: The relevant specifications in the data sheet are VIL and VIH - input low voltage and input high voltage.  You'll see that the driver will treat anything below 1.5V as "low" and anything above 2.3V as "high", so you can have some rather substantial spikes on your input and the controller won't do anything you don't want it to do.  Compare this with a randomly selected controller, say the ZXBM5210, that has a "low" input voltage (separately specified as VFWDL and VREFL) of 0 to 0.8V.

Comment: One might well ask, "why do logic inputs need *such special* treatment"? Answer: This chip's ground connection is **common** for both logic signals and high-current H-bridge currents. Poor wiring practice causes no end of problems where high-currents feed back through ground wiring to foul logic control signals, or confuse a driving microcontroller. Such faults are outside a chip manufacturers control, but a good data sheet might point out this possible trap.